# Error when creating db with Blog engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I've installed a [RefineryCMS](http://www.refinerycms.com) application, and everything was working fine until I decided to install its Blog engine.

We I ran the app migrations (including Blog) from scratch, I've received the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'custom_title' in 'field list': INSERT INTO `pages`  (`browser_title`, `path`, `meta_description`, `created_at`, `link_url`, `custom_title_type`, `draft`, `title`, `skip_to_first_child`, `deletable`, `updated_at`, `position`, `rgt`, `custom_title`, `meta_keywords`, `parent_id`, `menu_match`, `lft`, `show_in_menu`, `depth`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-03-10 16:32:08', '/blog', 'none', 0, 'Blog', 0, 0, '2011-03-10 16:32:08', 2, 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, '^/blogs?(/|/.+?|)$', 7, 1, NULL)
```

I've seen this is a [known issue](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms-blog/issues/50), but I cannot find a neat solution for both development and production environments.

BTW, I saw this happening with a custom engine installed by me using `rails g engine_name` command. The weird thing is that it doesn't happen if you run these migrations after all the previous ones have been run before. It just happens when runnning all the app migrations from scratch.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

This is my `db/seeds/refinerycms_blog.rb` file looks like after the comment I've received here:

```
Page.reset_column_information

User.find(:all).each do |user|
  user.plugins.create(:name => "refinerycms_blog",
                      :position => (user.plugins.maximum(:position) || -1) +1)
end

page = Page.create(
  :title => "Blog",
  :link_url => "/blog",
  :deletable => false,
  :position => ((Page.maximum(:position, :conditions => {:parent_id => nil}) || -1)+1),
  :menu_match => "^/blogs?(\/|\/.+?|)$"
)

Page.default_parts.each do |default_page_part|
  page.parts.create(:title => default_page_part, :body => nil)
end
```

But it's still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the top of the blog seeds files that it copied into db/seeds/:

```
Page.reset_column_information
```

Comment: This is not solving the issue. I'll edit the post in order to update it with this code.